# Create custom Imageview component that has a custom picture frame

Tags: android, imageview, android-canvas, custom-component

I would like to build a custom component (extending from ImageView I guess) that display an image inside a frame specified by the user (the frame is a custom image) with inner rounded corners (Pinterest user icon like).

I started finding how to compose two bitmaps but it is a difficult matter so I am wondering if there is some opensource component/tutorial to better understand how to achive it.

The frame picture is a nine-patch png (I didn't understand how to load and scale it properly into a bitmap).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out [this](http://nextlevelandroid.com/?p=78?)

Seems like it does the job, although I'm not sure how to implement.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I edited the question. I would like to achieve rounded corners in the inner image inside a frame.